# Instagram ?__a=1 api returns html in backend but not in curl

Tags: api, instagram

i've a problem with the web api of instagram https://instagram.com/user?__a=1 which returns basic json info about the user.
I've a private dashboard which should get data from about 2k instagram accounts in background each day to be shown in the dashboard.

Currently i'm doing a simple okHttp get from the backend, with a delay of 1 second between each other. My problem is that from the second or third, it returns the html related to www.instagram.com/login..

My constraint is, when i'm doing that with a curl, it does not happend..I've tried to set the user agent of a google chrome but is not working.

Does someone knows how can i do it? I know there is a graph API but as I said my app is private so they cannot see it to approve it..